# How to show Kinect depth data in millimeters

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, depth

I'm creating a program that can take two screenshots from Kinect (one IR-Image and one Depth-Image), load it directly into two Picture boxes, and then measure the Position of a Point in the IR screenshot by clicking the mouse.

I don't have a Problem to get x- & y- Position in the IR screenshot, what I Need is also the depth in mm - considering that IR and depth Image were taken from the same camera, so when I click the mouse it should link the x- & y- coordinates to the depth Image to take the depth value in mm.

My idea was to Access the variable **short depth = depthPixels[i].Depth;** in the method **SensorDepthFrameReady**. But why didn't it work? And why is the depth image shown in grayscale instead of RGB (unlike in Kinect Studio)?

```
private void SensorDepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
 using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
 {
  if (depthFrame != null)
  {
  depthFrame.CopyDepthImagePixelDataTo(this.depthPixels);
  int colorPixelDDIndex = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < this.depthPixels.Length; ++i)
  {
   short depth = depthPixels[i].Depth;
   ...
  }
  this.colorBitmapDD.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmapDD.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmapDD.PixelHeight),this.colorPixelsDD,this.colorBitmapDD.PixelWidth * sizeof(int),0);
  }
 }
}

private void imageIR_MouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
 System.Windows.Point mousePoint = e.GetPosition(imageIR);
 double xpos_IR = mousePoint.X;
 double ypos_IR = mousePoint.Y;
 lbCoord.Content = "x- & y- Koordinate [pixel]: " + xpos_IR + " ; " + ypos_IR;
 zpos.Content = "z- Koordinate [mm]: " + depth;
}
```

Any idea to solve the Problem? Thanks in advance.

Screenshot of main program:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bljQ9.jpg

Comment: Where do you set the `depth` variable used in your `imageIR_MouseClick`-handler?

Comment: zpos.Content = "z- Koordinate [mm]: " + depth; -> Direct access to the local variable still doesn't work even if I Change the method to public void.

Comment: One option would be to save each depth value with it's x and y values in a global variable. Maybe a `Dictionary<Point,short>`. And than in your `MouseClick`-handler read it: `zpos.Content = "z- Koordinate [mm]: " + _depthDic[new Point(xpos_IR,ypos_IR)];`

Comment: Sorry to ask some dumb question, but I'm very new to programming. So Point contains 2 values: xpos_IR and ypos_IR, how do I declare this in global variable? Something like: **Private Dictionary<Point (xpos_IR,ypos_IR), short depth> depthDic** ?

Comment: Have a look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to save each depth value with it's x and y values in a global variable. Maybe a `Dictionary<Point,short>`. And than in your MouseClick-handler read it: `zpos.Content = "z- Koordinate [mm]: " + _depthDic[new Point(xpos_IR,ypos_IR)];`

You declare your global variable through `private Dictionary<Point,short> _depthDic = new Dictionary<Point,short>();`

And set it in your SensorDepthFrameReady-handler:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.depthPixels.Length; ++i)
{
   Point coords = new Point(depthPixels[i].X, depthPixels[i].Y);
   _depthDic[coords] = depthPixels[i].Depth;
 ...
}
```

**Edit**: Another approach. Create a global field which holds the current `DepthImageFrame`. Save this `DepthImageFrame` in your SensorDepthFrameReady-method:

```
private DepthImageFrame _depthImageFrame;
private bool _imageUsing;
private void SensorDepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
 using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
 {
  if (depthFrame != null)
  {
      if (!_imageUsing)
          _depthImageFrame = depthFrame;

      //your code
  }
 }
}
```

Then create a method which returns the depth value to a specific x and y value:

```
private int GetDepthValue(DepthImageFrame imageFrame, int x, int y)
{
   _imageUsing = true;
   short[] pixelData = new short[imageFrame.PixelDataLength];
   imageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);
   var result = ((ushort)pixelData[x + y * imageFrame.Width])>>3 ;
   _imageUsing = false;
   return result;
}
```

And finally show the values on mouse-click:

```
private void imageIR_MouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
 System.Windows.Point mousePoint = e.GetPosition(imageIR);
 double xpos_IR = mousePoint.X;
 double ypos_IR = mousePoint.Y;
 lbCoord.Content = "x- & y- Koordinate [pixel]: " + xpos_IR + " ; " + ypos_IR;
 if (_depthImageFrame != null)
     zpos.Content = "z- Koordinate [mm]: " + GetDepthValue(_depthImageFrame, Convert.toInt16(mousePoint.X),Convert.toInt16(mousePoint.Y));
}
```

Maybe this could help you: http://www.i-programmer.info/ebooks/practical-windows-kinect-in-c/3802-using-the-kinect-depth-sensor.html

Comment: It shows an error: 'Microsoft.Kinect.DepthImagePixel' does not contain a definition for 'Y' and no extension method 'Y' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Kinect.DepthImagePixel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Since I don't program with kinect I don't know which properties exists or not. Apperently the DepthImagePixel class hasn't got a X and Y property. So you have to find a way by yourself to get the X and Y coordinate of the DepthPixel, but the rest should work.

Comment: Yes, but it has the same height & width as the IR Image as it was taken from the same camera. So how do I translate the x- & y- coordinate from the IR Image into the depth image? In the Kinect Studio it Looks like this: http://m84i.img-up.net/Unbenanntf5ba.png?l=de

Comment: Or is it possible to Access **double xpos_IR = mousePoint.X;**
and **double ypos_IR = mousePoint.Y;** in the method **imageIR_MouseClick**? Because if it's possible, then I just declare **depthPixels[i].X** as **mousePoint.X** right?

Comment: No, because you have no mousePoint in the SensorDepthFrameReady-method. Have a look at my edit ;)

Comment: For the first Moment it appears not to have any error, however during program's running, it returns an error message: **ObjectDisposedException was unhandled, cannot Access a disposed object. Object Name: 'DepthImageFrame'**; the Troubleshooting tips told me to make sure I haven't released a resource before attempting to use it. What does it exactly means? Should I add some condition like **if (imageFrame == null)** ?

Comment: Oh anyway: **toInt16** is not correct (it's capital sensitive) and it should be **ToInt16**

Comment: I think the _depthImageFrame gets set new while its instance is used in the GetDepthValue-method and can't be found after that. Try to find a solution by yourself. ;)

Comment: There is a formula to calculate the depth in meter in this page: http://shiffman.net/p5/kinect/ ; but in which method should I integrate it? Directly in SensorDepthFrameReady ? Because Kinect Studio Depth Viewer can just do it perfectly: http://m84i.img-up.net/Unbenanntf5ba.png?l=de -> Problem is it's compiled so I don't know which tricks they're using.

Comment: You already have a method which calculates the depth, why do you want to integrate another? Besides the code on this page is not C#, it is C++, so you cant just copy and paste it. How about using my hint and your brain to solve your problem without looking up every little step on google? -.-

Comment: Because I don't have any Basic programming at all. But you said that the GetDepthValue-method doesn't work? So apparently I still have to access the variable **short depth** in SensorDepthFrameReady right?

Comment: Well maybe just simplify the question: how do I call the variable **depth** in **SensorDepthFrameReady** from the Methode **imageIR_MouseClick** ? I suppose it has to be a real time calling. It Freaks me out because I can't create a method with a two Events happening at the same time (**MouseEventArgs** together with **DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs**)

Comment: It is working according the code I copy it from here: http://www.i-programmer.info/ebooks/practical-windows-kinect-in-c/3802-using-the-kinect-depth-sensor.html - it will show some change in distance, however I don't know how which exactly which point it's tracking but when I move some object, it tracks the movement and show the distance in mm. It is not really what I want - because it should work after I take the screenshot and read the coordinate when I click the IR Image. Any other Suggestion?

Comment: Wait!! Of course it's only tracking the Point in the middle: **depthFrame.Width / 2** and **depthFrame.Height / 2**

Comment: I never said that the GetDepthValue-method doesn't work, I think it works, but you have to modify it. Have a look at my edit. But if you haven't got any programming skills, I would recommend starting with something more simple...

Comment: I can't start something more simple because this is a part of some of my work. Anyway, I got it work. Now I only have to find how **double xpos_IR = mousePoint.X** and **double ypos_IR = mousePoint.Y** can saved in a temporary Cache as a global variable. So when I click the screenshot button and locate the cursor in the IR Image it will Show the depth value.

Comment: you just have to make them global by putting them outside a method. now you can use them in any method in this class.

Comment: I tried it like this (see my edited answer): **private short _pixelData;
        public short pixelData
        {
            get { return _pixelData; }
            set
        //{
            //using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
            {
                short[] _pixelData = new short[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];
                d = (ushort)_pixelData[x + y * depthFrame.Width];
                d = d >> 3;
            }
 }** But then it returned a message: 'pixelData.get' must declare a Body because it is not marked Abstract or extern. What does it exactly means?